# Angular and builtin javascript map function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pretty new to angular so maybe I'm missing something obvious. I have a model with collection of objects with own properties; and I'm trying to create a csv value out of `Text` property of that object. I've tried few things and got it to work with both `ng-repeat` and by calling a function. However what I thought was the most straight forward way of doing this is not quite working.

```
{{item.Keywords.map(function (kw) { return kw.Text; }).join(', ')}}
```

In this example `join` works just fine (i see `object` separated by commas), however when combined with map it's unable to interpret it and just prints out it as is. Is there a trick to using `map` that I'm missing?

Comment: I think you're taking angular expressions a bit too far. You don't want to include functions in your templates.

Answer (score 5):

Angular expressions can't do everything you can do in javascript. Check out the [angular docs for expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) for more detail on what they can and can't do. I don't think you can declare a function in an angular expression so that is probably why your particular example is not working.

In general you should try to keep the logic in a view to a minimum. You can always just move the logic from your expression into a function on the controller.